# Where can I store an XML file for the browser to read using ASP.Net MCV

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xml, file

I would like to have a xml file on my website that holds temporary information from a database. When I use VSCode to do so, it works just fine; but when I use my actual ASP.Net Web Application, it does not. I assume it has to do with the file path that I am using, any help would be greatly appreciated!

ASP.Net
C#

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/phones.xml");
foreach (var pm in Model)
{
     // add each model to xml
}
```

JS

```
const MakePhoneOBJ = (xmlFile) => {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            xmlFunc(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlFile, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

const xmlFunc = (xml) => {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Element");
    for (let i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
        // Do something with the file contents
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="MakePhoneOBJ('@path');">
</body>
```

Comment: Do you generate phones.xml file on a request, or it is a real file stored in App_data?
Also, I think store files in App_data folder is nota good idea. Did you try any other location?

Comment: @EvgenyGorb Do you generate phones.xml file on a request? Yes, but the file does show up in App_Data after I start the IIS. Did you try another location? Yes, I tried creating a ~/Temp/phones.xml, but it still does not give any data i.e. 404 error

Comment: Have you tried to get that file directly using browser? Just enter in the browser's address line: `<your site name>/Temp/phones.xml`. What does it return?

Comment: @EvgenyGorb using ~/Temp/phones.xml actually did bring up my xml document whereas using ~/App_Data/phones.xml does not, shows the 404 page. I guess that means that I need to be using another folder other than App_Data. It still does not explain why the js cannot request the path though, even if I use 'Temp'

Comment: How about using jquery to send requests to the server?
Also, did you compare requests sent by you and by your js (press F12 in your browser and navigate to Network tab)? Do both that addresses the same?

Comment: @EvgenyGorb I got my js to read the file but I had to paste in the direct path into the xmlhttp.open() function. I believe that this would have to have something to do with the way I am passing the path into the function in the first place. When I log the Server.MapPath("~/Temp/phones.xml"); I get a string with no backslashes, which is probably done by some sort of sanitation in the background. I think the solution is to get a real path and pass it in. As far as using jquery, I would prefer to not, mainly because I do not know it very well, but also because its jquery.

Comment: Can you post here both versions of urls?

Comment: As far as the paths, I will use `string path = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/phones.xml");` to generate the local path and create the folder. And for the http request path I will use `string url_path = (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/Temp/phones.xml");` and pass that into the html as `<body onload="MakePhoneOBJ('@url_path');"></body>`

Comment: No, I need urls that you see in developer console, Network tab, when you make requests to the xml directly and using js

Comment: The URL for the xml file is https://localhost:44309/Temp/phones.xml . And the URL for the main page is https://localhost:44309/Home/PhoneDatabase . When on the main page, I could not see the xml file until I used the code above. The code above works though, thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the path that I was using: '~/App_Data/phones.xml'. Instead, I created a temp folder and used that path

```
string path = (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/Temp/phones.xml";
```

and passed it into my js function using razor.